# SAS - Proc Compare - show ALL duplicates

Tags: compare, sas, procedure

whilst using the PROC COMPARE is SAS, is it possible to list all duplicates found? By default a message will be displayed stating the first duplicate found and the total number of duplicates.

i.e:

```
data x1;
  input x $ y $ z $ ;
  datalines;
   222 test abc
   qqq test abc
   aaa test abc
   222 test abc
   222 test abc
   ;
run;


data y1;
  input x $ y $ z $ ;
  datalines;
   222 test abc
   qqq test abc
   aaa test abc
   222 test abc
   222 test abc
   ;
run;

***********************************;
*** sort data;
***********************************;

proc sort data=x1; 
   by x y; 
run;

proc sort data=y1; 
   by x y; 
run;

***********************************;
*** compare data;
***********************************;

proc compare listvar
   base=x1
   compare = y1;
   id x y;
run;

************** END *****************;
```

output

The SAS System

```
                                  The COMPARE Procedure                                       
                            Comparison of WORK.X1 with WORK.Y1                                
                                      (Method=EXACT)                                          

                                    Data Set Summary                                          

                Dataset           Created          Modified  NVar    NObs                     

                WORK.X1  23OCT14:16:03:38  23OCT14:16:03:38     3       5                     
                WORK.Y1  23OCT14:16:03:38  23OCT14:16:03:38     3       5                     


                                    Variables Summary                                         

                          Number of Variables in Common: 3.                                   
                          Number of ID Variables: 2.                                          





             WARNING: The data set WORK.X1 contains a duplicate observation at observation    
                      number 2.                                                               
             NOTE: At observation 2 the current and previous ID values are:                   
                   x=222 y=test.                                                              
             NOTE: Further warnings for duplicate observations in this data set will not be   
                   printed.                                                                   
             WARNING: The data set WORK.Y1 contains a duplicate observation at observation    
                      number 2.                                                               
             NOTE: At observation 2 the current and previous ID values are:                   
                   x=222 y=test.                                                              
             NOTE: Further warnings for duplicate observations in this data set will not be   
                   printed.                                                                   







                                   Observation Summary                                        

                   Observation      Base  Compare  ID                                         

                   First Obs           1        1  x=222 y=test                               
                   Last  Obs           5        5  x=qqq y=test                               

             Number of Observations in Common: 5.                                             
             Number of Duplicate Observations found in WORK.X1: 2.                            
             Number of Duplicate Observations found in WORK.Y1: 2.                          
             Total Number of Observations Read from WORK.X1: 5.                               
             Total Number of Observations Read from WORK.Y1: 5.                               

             Number of Observations with Some Compared Variables Unequal: 0.                  
             Number of Observations with All Compared Variables Equal: 5.                     

             NOTE: No unequal values were found. All values compared are exactly equal.
```

@ Joe - thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Close voter, I have no idea why you would think this belongs on Super User.  SAS is a programming language and this is a perfectly reasonable question to ask.

Comment: RBRT, your question would be received better if you included an example of what you see (a simple dataset and code to reproduce what you're seeing, and often an example of what you want to see instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proc Freq might be a good approach to find duplicates.  Then just print them out with a Proc Print.

```
PROC FREQ; 
 TABLES keyvar / noprint out=keylist;
RUN; 
PROC PRINT data=keylist; 
 WHERE count ge 2; 
RUN;
```

Comment: You could even include the `where` clause in the out=, ie `out=keylist(where=(count ge 2))`, which would make this work even better I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to get the log or listing to list more than just the first duplicate, if that's what you're going after, using the ID statement.

What you are likely best off doing is using the `OUTALL` option, and outputting the results to a dataset (if you're not already).  Then it would be fairly easy to see the duplicates.

For example:

```
data class2 class3;
  set sashelp.class;
    output;
    output;
    output class3;
run;

proc compare base=class2 compare=class3 out=outclass outall;
  id name;
run;
```

You could also use the BY statement along with the ID statement, if it's sorted; then you'll still have duplicates, but each BY Group has a separate report, so you'd see the duplicates there.

```
proc compare base=class2 compare=class3 out=outclass outall;
  by name;
  id name;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding exact number of duplicates for each id may be better suited for proc sql.

Something like:

```
proc sql;
create table x2 as select
*,
count(id_var)
from x1
group by x,y,z;
quit;
```

This could reveal any duplicate rows in either dataset.